# Unity RectTransform.sizeDelta doesn't change size

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics, resize

I am trying to change size of a gameobject that has `TextMeshPro - Text (UI)` component to fit his parent. Here is the code.

```
static public Cube CreateCube(Transform parent, Vector2 anchors, Vector2 position)
{
    Cube c = Instantiate(cubePrefab); // prefab has Cube component

    var tr = (RectTransform)c.transform;
    tr.SetParent(parent); // canvas or other 2d object
    tr.anchorMin = tr.anchorMax = anchors;
    tr.anchoredPosition = position;

    var textObj = new GameObject("Text");

    var textTr = textObj.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
    textTr.SetParent(tr);
    textTr.anchorMin = textTr.anchorMax = Vector2.one / 2; // anchors at the center of the parent
    textTr.anchoredPosition = Vector2.zero;

    // tr.sizeDelta is Vector2(60, 60) from prefab;
    print(new Vector2(tr.sizeDelta.x, tr.sizeDelta.y * 2 / 3)); // Vector2(60, 40)
    textTr.sizeDelta = new Vector2(tr.sizeDelta.x, tr.sizeDelta.y * 2 / 3); // width is the same as parent's width
    // height is two thirds of parent's height
    print(textTr.sizeDelta); // also Vector2(60, 40)

    var text = textObj.AddComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
    text.text = "Test";
    text.fontSize = 14;
    text.alignment = TextAlignmentOptions.Center;

    return c;
}
```

Second `print` shows that `sizeDelta` has been set, but in the inspector and on the scene size is (200, 50) like without `textTr.sizeDelta = ...` line.

But if I add

```
private void Start()
{
    ((RectTransform)transform.GetChild(0)).sizeDelta = new Vector2(60, 40);
}
```

into the `Cube` class, it will work. Why doesn't it work when I create text?

Objects hierarchy:

-> Some 2d object

---> Object with `Cube` component

-----> Text object

[image]

Comment: Anything overruling your change like e.g. a `ContentSizeFittet`, `HorizontalLayoutGroup` etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canvas hierarchy is calculated not immediately when you create and add new objects to it, and it often may lead to some unpredictable results. The reccomended workaround is to wait at least 1 frame after the object is created and only then apply changes for properties like sizeDelta. You can do this using Coroutine and skip 1 frame with `yield return null`. As an alternative for you specific use case, you can try to use [RectTransform.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors.html) instead of directly setting sizeDelta, try this approach first I'd say.

```
    textRt.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors(RectTransform.Axis.Horizontal,  60);
    textRt.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors(RectTransform.Axis.Vertical,  40);
```

Comment: Yeah. I've thought about this and coroutine has actually helped. But I need method return some value, but I read that coroutine can't do this. So I've used `Start` method for this.

P.s.: `SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors` doesn't work.

Comment: wow, what a gem